# Upgraded PHP & Symfony, now getting "Call to a member function render() on null" using Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I recently upgraded PHP from 7.4 to 8.2 and with that, I've upgraded Symfony, Twig to the current versions. (Twig 3.5) Unfortunately that has now broken my application. I've managed to fix everything up till now but I'm stuck with the Template and and it's function to render pages using Twig.

The error is:

> ```
> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function render() on null in /var/www/html/website/lib/Template.php:79
> ```

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/website/lib/Handler.php(44): MyProject\Template::render()
#1 /var/www/html/website/lib/Handler.php(61): MyProject\Handler::error()
#2 [internal function]: MyProject\Handler::exception()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/website/lib/Template.php on line 79<
```

This is on the initial index page to the website. The code in question is:

```
    public static function render($template, $args = [], $returnOutput = false)
    {
        $arg['user'] = Auth::user();
        $output = self::$twig->render($template . '.twig', $args);

        if (getenv('STAGE') == 'dev') {
            $output = self::$purifierExtension->getLog() . $output;
        }

        if ($returnOutput) {
            return $output;
        } else {
            echo $output;
        }
    }
```

The page that is calling this function is this one:

```
    MyProject\Template::header('MyProject', true);
    
    $user = MyProject\Auth::user();
    $args = [
        'error' => false,
        'redirect' => isset($_GET['redirect']) && $_GET['redirect'] ? $_GET['redirect'] : 'main.php',
        'username' => ''
    ];
    
    
    if (!$user && isset($_POST['username'])) {
        MyProject\Form::validateCsrf('login');
    
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $passwrd = $_POST['password'];
    
    
        // query for matching user/password
        try {
            $MyProjectuserid = MyProject\Auth::login($username, $passwrd);
        } catch (UnauthorizedHttpException $ex) {
            $args['error'] = 'Could not login. Please try again.';
            $args['username'] = $username;
        }
    }
    
    if (MyProject\Auth::user()) {
        MyProject\Alert::redirect($args['redirect']);
    }
    
    MyProject\Template::render('index', $args);
    
    MyProject\Template::footer();
```

I have checked file permissions, I have removed and reinstalled the packages using Composer, and I have commented out various lines, leaving just this line as the culprit:

```
    $output = self::$twig->render($template . '.twig', $args);
```

Any suggestions or help you can offer will be most gratefully received!

**Additional info:**

Thanks for your comment. I confess I have inherited this site and am not familiar with Symfony/Twig (I'm more of a dba person). The only initialisation I can find are these:
in Template.php

```
    private static $twig;
        self::$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
        self::$twig->addFunction($fn);
        self::$twig->addExtension(self::$purifierExtension);
        self::$twig->addExtension(self::$answerTypeExt);
    $output = self::$twig->render($template . '.twig', $args);
        return self::$twig;
```

and in Handler.php

```
    public static function init()
    {
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
        self::$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
```

This site used to work until a recent PHP/Symfony stack upgrade. So is this something in the logic used to be acceptable but isn't any more?

Bootstrap.php loads various files:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php'); 
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv; 
$dotenv = new Dotenv(); 
$dotenv->load(DIR.'/../.env');
MyProject\Handler::init(); 
MyProject\DB::init();
MyProject\Auth::init();
MyProject\Template::init();
MyProject\Form::init();
```

Comment: According to the error you are receiving `self::$twig` is `NULL`, make sure you are actually initializing `$twig` before trying to render the code. We can't help you unless you provide more debugging details, e.g. where is `self::$twig` initalized/set

Comment: I've added additional info on this. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are `Handler` and `Template` connected?

Comment: To me it's strange you have two instances of `twig`. If I were you I'd replace the `self::$twig` inside `Template` with `Handler::$twig` or `Handler::getTwig()` if `$twig` is private